# Send a text message from R

Tags: r, sms

I know you can send an email from R with sendMail, and you can tweet with twitteR.  Is there any way to send a text message from an R script?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All of the major US cell phone carriers allow you to send text messages using the standard email (SMTP) protocol.  You can send a text message by sending an email to the phone.  Here are the different email domains for the different carriers:

http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

Answer (score 8):

I always struggled to get my mail configured correctly to send an email from R. But if you are on a Mac and use Mac Messages, you can send a text using Messages with an AppleScript.

So run the following code in `R` right in your script:

```
send_text = function(message){
    system(paste('osascript -e \'tell application "Messages"\' -e \'send "', message, '" to buddy "555-555-5555" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)\' -e \'end tell\''))
}
```

Just change the number to the phone number you want to text!

Comment: Did you integrate this into R? If not - how did you run this?

Comment: Yes! Right in the R script. Clarified above.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Wonder if I can deploy this to the cloud and automate it