# Function to have R tell you its done running or processing a job

Tags: r

Currently, when executing long jobs in `R`, I put a call to `alarm()` at the end of it so that I know my job is done.

What other methods exist?  Any good hacks or custom functions?

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6543070/324364)?

Comment: This has been discussed before. I personally liked [the idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3367275/2338862) of sending yourself a tweet when it's done. Otherwise, if you're still sitting at your machine while this is happening, put in a `tcltk::tkmessageBox` call to create a popup.

Comment: Hey @Joran, I dont think this is a duplicate, since I am wondering if there are methods ALTERNATE to what is discussed in that question (ie, not just making a beep, which is what I currently use).  However, the other question you linked to (using SMS) is a helpful answer

Comment: Well, both questions are essentially asking for lists of alternatives, which is technically out of bounds already, so I was just trying to be efficient and group all the answers together, since people landing on one question will almost certainly find the answers at the other question useful too.

Answer (score 8):

At risk of losing all my reputation points:

1) Get a RaspberryPI and some Arduino stuff and a thermistor

2) Jam the thermistor into the output vent of your computer

3) Connect the thermistor leads to an A/D converter

4) Program the RaspberryPI to observe the thermistor temperature dropping from an elevated temperature to near room-temp

5) Upon such an event occurring, have the RaspberryPI send a remote command to your audio cabinet (which is connected to a set of Altec-Lansing studio monitors) to play The Doors'  "The End" .

Answer (score 4):

Self promotion alert:

I use my own GitHub repo of borrowed code to use Gmail to send me an email and a text message.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/trinker/gmailR

Here are the examples for email and text:

```
gmail(to=c("bob@gmail.com", "janr@hotmail.com"), password = "password", 
    attachment="path/to/file.pdf")

gmail(to=cell2email(5555555555, "sprint"), password = "password")
```

Comment: Hey, that's the password on my luggage!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, do you work at my company?  That very same reference was just sent out around 5 minutes ago!

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Not unless you work for Louis Chenevert :-)