# How to send external message in R (without providing sender account)

Tags: r, email, sms, message

Is it possible to send an external message (e.g., and email or SMS text, tweet, etc.) via R without providing a `sending` account?

If so, how would one send a quick message to an email account or mobile device using R in such a way that doesn't require a `sender` account input?

- Example usage: to inform user when code is done running.

I've seen other SO posts discussing how to send emails (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412265/how-do-you-send-email-from-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885660/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-from-r-in-windows)) and [texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543070/send-a-text-message-from-r) via R, but none of these sources discusses the possibility of doing so *without* providing an explicit `sender` account (i.e, credentials).

Disclaimer: 
This is not for sneaky business, but rather to simplify security/privacy.

Comment: If your users (development team) uses Slack, you can open slack incoming webhooks. Which allows you to send messages to slack without providing credentials (it will come from a bot). There is a package 'slackr' that can do it

Comment: presumably without running your own sendmail daemon ... ?

Comment: You don't actually have to provide a valid sender info using `sendmail`. `sendmail(from='a@a',to='yourEmail@domain.com',subject='subject',msg='body')` just works. The message will probably drop to spam at first so just tell your email client that it is legit