# r send a text message with AppleScript in a function that includes the message and number as parameters

Tags: r, applescript

The question and answer at this link
[Send a text message from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543070/send-a-text-message-from-r)
use a function to create the AppleScript. I have copied it below

```
send_text = function(message){
  system(paste('osascript -e \'tell application "Messages"\' -e \'send "', message, 
               '" to buddy "xxx-yyy-zzzz" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)\' -e \'end tell\''))
}
send_text("Hello world")
```

I'd like to modify the function so it can take both the message and the number, like this - `send_text = function(number, message)`

I can't figure out how the paste works to replace `xxx-yyy-zzz` with the variable `number`.

Comment: Could you pass the number with the ```-``` 's as a string? Then replace current code with ```... buddy ', number, ' of ...``` ? Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paste` function works by combining everything separated by commas into a single string. All you have to do is extract the "xxx-yyy-zzzz" from the sentence, replace it with `number`, and use commas.

```r
send_text = function(message, number){
    paste('osascript -e \'tell application "Messages"\' -e \'send "', message, 
            '" to buddy \"', number, '\" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)\' -e \'end tell\'')
}
send_text("Hello world", "555-888-0909")
#> [1] "osascript -e 'tell application \"Messages\"' -e 'send \" Hello world \" to buddy \" 555-888-0909 \" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)' -e 'end tell'"
```

Or alternatively you could use string interpolation from the *glue* package and insert the variable directly into the string with brackets.

```r
send_text_2 <- function(message, number){
    glue::glue(
        'osascript -e \'tell application "Messages"\' -e \'send "{message}" to buddy "{number}" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)\' -e \'end tell\''
    )
}

send_text_2("Hello world", "555-888-0909")
#> osascript -e 'tell application "Messages"' -e 'send "Hello world" to buddy "555-888-0909" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)' -e 'end tell'
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>