# r send text messages on a Mac

Tags: r, applescript

This script (which is a modification of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543070/send-a-text-message-from-r))

```
send_text = function(number, message){
  system(paste('osascript -e \'tell application "Messages"\' -e \'send "', message, 
               '" to buddy \"', number, '\" of (service 1 whose service type is iMessage)\' -e \'end tell\''))
}
send_text("xxx-yyy-zzzz", "Some message")
```

Works as expected when sending a text from an Apple environment to another Apple environment. But fails when sending to a Windows-based environment. It leaves the message in the Messages app with a `Not Delivered` error message. If you click it you have the option to send as a text message which does work. I don't know anything about AppleScript so I asked chatGPT to come up with a version that sends only text messages.

Its modification was to add "with text" after `iMessage) with text` which didn't work. Still had to click send as text message in the Messages app. What did chatGPT get wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to replace `service type is iMessage` with

```
service type is SMS
```

`SMS` is the generic form of a text message. `iMessage` is Apple's special (proprietary?) form of text messages.